# Find all references from Visual Studio is broken with F# members

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

I have a simple F# type (simulating a ViewModel)

```
type MainViewModel() as self =
    let mutable internalBU = Some "Test - BU"
```

where the member property is defined as usual (for example as follows)

```
    member x.InternalBU 
        with get() : string = internalBU.Value 
        and set (value:string) =internalBU <- Some value
```

I use it in a trivial line (8)

```
    let findME name =
        printfn "Hello %s" (self.InternalBU.Replace(" - BU", name))
```

Now when I search for references from the `InternalBU` definition

[image]

I can't find the line 8.
It seems a bug, because I've tried the same search from line 8 (which is not what would happen in a real world case however) and Visual Studio finds the F# reference for that line.

[image]

Comment: You realize there is an infinite loop here, right?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin this is reduced from a real program of mine, so either there is a infinite loop because of a typo/error in my reduction or it is in the original program (but that is working fine and it has been in prod for years, so I'd say the first one...). Let me read again what I've written ... I could not spot it, but anyway it should not be related to the issue, I guess

Comment: Well, I may have been too harsh. It's not an infinite loop, but perhaps reading an underinitialized value. Look: `internalBU` is initialized by calling `self.InternalBU`'s getter, which is implemented by reading the value of `internalBU`.

Comment: Fixed the infinite loop or the underinitialized value, etc..., thank you

Comment: Does the problem with finding references still persist? (also: you haven't replaced the screenshots)

Comment: @FyodorSoikin let mereplace the screenshot :-) yes, it persists, a little different but it is here

Comment: @FyodorSoikin screenshots replaced, thank you

Comment: What version of VS 2019?

Comment: @JimFoye VisualStudio.16.Release/16.7.7

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Find-References-does-not-show-code-anymo/1159434

Comment: @JimFoye I'm in the process of updating to the latest, downloading a few GB now.... Thank you

Comment: @JimFoye all this time to upgrade to VisualStudio.16.Release/16.9.3 :-( but finally it works :-) if you want to post your comments as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I previously reported this as a bug to MS and it was fixed in Visual Studio 16.8:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Find-References-does-not-show-code-anymo/1159434